# Java servlet cuts off file extension

Tags: java, servlets

I'm attempting to serve local or proxy files via my Java application.

With something like this

```
    @ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/{file}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable("file") String f) throws IOException {

    String filename = URLDecoder.decode(f, "UTF-8");
    File file = new File("resources/files/", filename);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());

}
```

With an example URL such as

> example.com/file/out2KP2_1.mp4

I'm getting the error:

> Problem accessing /file/out2KP2_1.mp4. Reason:
>
> resources\files\out2KP2_1 Caused by:
>
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: resources\files\out2KP2_1  at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)

If I add a trailing / to the url and requestMapping, it works, but on iOS and a few other places the video player doesn't seem to like loading a file with a trailing slash so it doesn't suit my purposes.

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the mark down. Take it you didn't know the answer!?

It's a problem with Spring, you have to add :.+ to the file URL variable

i.e.    @RequestMapping(value = "/file/{file:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)